# Having problems in running lumen on xampp virtual host

Tags: php, apache, xampp, lumen

I am having trouble running a lumen site(website2) in xampp on Ubuntu through virtual host.
This what my hosts file look like.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost 
127.0.0.1 website1.local 
127.0.0.1 website2.local
```

And here is my what my httpd-vhosts.conf looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@website2.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/website2/public/"
    ServerName website2.local
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@website1.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/website1/"
    ServerName website1.local 
</VirtualHost>
```

The website1 works fine, but when I access website2 which is a lumen project gets this error in chrome.

```
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Have tried adding this in httpd-vhosts.conf but doesnt work.

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/website2/public/">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

When I run the lumen project by terminal using

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

It runs perfect. What could be the problem?.

Thanks.

Comment: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED means problem with host file. not sure how it works in linux but did you tried to clear dns cache ?

Comment: Hi @MaulikGangani yeah i have chrome://net-internals/#dns